# How to use application settings in .NET 3.5 Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, settings

I am trying to store a type of `System.Collection.Queue`. The queue will only contain strings. The issue is that when I attempt to use it, it is always Null.

```
Settings.Default.CorrectionsDescription.Enqueue(textString);
```

I get the following error.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have gotten `StringCollection` to work fine, but I need a [FIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) queue.

How do you initialize the queue, in the Settings or through code? When I tried, it gave the error that it is read only.

Comment: are you sure that the queue in null, and not your textString ?

Comment: yeah i've even done .Enqueue("Hello World");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings usually only store data in very simple objects or collections (xml-serializable, even Dictionary<TKey, TValue> already causes problem!).

Queue has special semantics and is not very suitable for data storage.

I suggest to use **List<string>** or **StringCollection** to store settings and create **Queue** on start of your application based on that collection.

Saving is the same but in reverse order - create List from your Queue, put it into Settings class and save.

**Update:**

Standard settings mechanism uses XML serialization for object persistence.

Object implementing **IEnumerable<T>** must also have method **Add(T value)** to be *xml-serializable*. **Queue<T>** doesn't have such method so can't be successfully deserialized.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx%28vs.80)):

> XmlSerializer can process classes that implement IEnumerable or ICollection differently if they meet certain requirements. A class that implements IEnumerable must implement a public Add method that takes a single parameter

Comment: This is actually how I've implemented it so far but couldn't figure out why the Queue wouldn't work. It would simplify things if it would, but I understand a little more now after reading on xml-serializable. Thanks Konstantin

Comment: Added info why Queue is not serializable. I think that's the main problem when you are trying to use it in Settings.

Comment: All I'm storing in the queue is strings. No other types of objects. But I haven't been able to add anything to the Queue because it is Null. I can't get it to initialize using the Settings.setting file at design time, nor can i do it at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I have always just used:

```
if (Settings.Default.CorrectionsDescription == null)
{
    Settings.Default.CorrectionsDescription = new Queue();
}
```

at the program startup, but I would like to know of a better way as well.

Comment: I can't get this to work either... I would move on if it would. I keep getting the error. Property or indexer 'ConfigFilesTest.Properties.Settings.CorrectionsDescription' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: Perhaps the scope of your setting is set to "Application"... try to change it to "User", it will be writable